# create a post and broken image appeared (using paperclip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

I've installed imagemagick, paperclip, no prob with the migration and else.. but it shows that my image is broken named Missing, also tried to troubleshoot by copy a tutorial on youtube and other forums, but still, the same problem appeared.. only a post with a broken image.

here is the output I get:

[image]

Comment: hmmm can you show us model,view, and controller code ?

Comment: Was the image created? If so I presume it must be a path problem. But as @niceman says we need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Nahhh the problem is in the post.rb (models).. I change this :

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
```

to this :

```
has_attached_file :image
```

i don't know why the styles is the problem.. i thought it will resize the uploaded image.. the image appear but the size is random.. so i put this at views:

```
<%= image_tag @post.image.url,size:"400x400" %>
```

Problem solved